# How can positive energy fields negatively contribute to the mass?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, nuclear-physics, mass-energy

Mass decreases in the presence of attractive forces according to the formula : $\delta m=\frac{E}{c^2}$, where $E$ is the energy of the binding field. My problem is that field energy is always positive according to its formula $(|E|^2+|B|^2)$. Then how can the EM field contribute a negative mass?

Same goes for the nuclear force. Does the strong force field store negative energy??

Comment: @Prahar I'm talking about the situation where the mass of the unbroken system is lower than the sum of masses of the composing particles. The mass of the unbroken system is : sum of masses of composing particles plus mass contribution from the field glueing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a positive and a negative charge infinitely far apart. Each charge has a field around it and that field stores energy. The mass of the charged objects will include the energy of the fields around them.

Now we bring the objects together, and because they have opposite charges their fields will cancel each other i.e. the magnitude of the total field $E_1 + E_2$ will be less than the magnitudes of the individual fields. This mean the energy stored in the total field is less than the energies stored in the fields when the charged objects were infinitely far apart.

And now it should be obvious why the mass decreases as we bring the charged objects closer together. The thing that's tripping you up is that the energy in the total field is not negative. It is simply less than the energy in the total field when the charges are separated to infinity.

Comment: So, by individual masses, we mean the mass of the isolated "electron + field" system. We don't mean the bare mass of the electron. Is this, like, related to renormalisation? What $m$ do we use in the Langrangian for the electron's motion?

Comment: @RyderRude this can get very complicated very quickly once you start describing the electron using quantum field theory. The bottom line is that the constant that we call *the rest mass of the electron* is the total energy/c² where some of that energy is stored in the electric field of the electron.

Comment: Hey. I read about a calculation of an infinite electron self mass in the classical theory. Is this because the field near the surface of the electron diverges according to Coulomb's law? And hence there's an infinite mass contribution according to $m=\frac{E}{c^2}$. And then we have to renormalse the electron's bare mass to negative infinity even in the classical theory?

Comment: @RyderRude yes, but this is an artefact of assuming that the electron is a point charge. Quantum field theory tells us the electron is a far more complicated object than a simple point charge.